# Pass array as parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, parameter-passing

My professor suggested that we should also pass a integer size as the parameter :

```
int abc(const int data[], int size, int value) {
  int i= 0, ans= -1;

  while (i < size && ans == -1) {
    if (data[i] == value)
      ans= i;
    i++;
  }

  return ans;
}
```

However, I don't think it is necessary to add the integer size in the parameter. 
I think the function can be changed to:

```
int abc(const int data[], int value) {
  int i= 0, ans= -1;

  while (data[i]!=NULL) {
    if (data[i] == value)
      ans= i;
    i++;
  }

  return ans;
}
```

(I know that we are just passing the pointer of the first element of the array in to the function!)
Is the first version has more advantage than the second version?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So, what happens in your function when the value is not found in the array? Or if the value to be searched is 0?

Comment: How does your `abc` function know how long the array is ?

Comment: while (data[i]!=NULL) will iterate to the end

Comment: @overloading let's say `data` is a 3-element array, what happens when `i == 3` ?

Comment: I dunno why everyone is missing the point: `data[i]` is __not__ a pointer. sigh.

Comment: @DilipKumar It doesn't matter much. since NULL can be defined as constant 0. It can be quite nicely compared to values in the array. NULL is *not* always cast into `void*`

Comment: your professor is right

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, your compiler wants to slap you.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: That still would be meant as a null pointer constant. However, in most C compilers it is (and should be) `#define ((void *)0)` (and no, you should not cast `NULL`). A null pointer constant is different from the integer constant `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[i]!=NULL` for this to work, the element after the last element of the array should be `NULL`, which I think won't be the case. `int` cannot be compared with `NULL`.

---

*However, you can do something similar. You can use a **marker** to mark the end of the array*

**Choose some number that you are sure won't appear in the array** (may be you know the range of numbers in the array), lets say `99999`. Then save it after the last element (do remember you need an array of size one more then the elements you wanna keep). And then use that to check the end of array.

```
int abc(const int data[], int value) {
  int i= 0, ans= -1;

  while (data[i]!=99999) {
    if (data[i] == value)
      ans= i;
    i++;
  }

  return ans;
}
```

---

*If there is no information about the range*

**Then you have to send the size of the array along with other parameters to the function.**

Comment: isn't `data[i]` a _value_?

Answer (score 3):

`data[i]` being an `int` value should not be compared against `NULL`. That's just not correct.

You *should* pass the size as a separate parameter.

Comment: @MichaelWalz right. but isn't is the reason of all confusions here? :)

Answer (score 2):

Passing the size as a parameter is a good practice that can protect you from a segmentation fault if the array is malformed.

If you are absolutely certain that the array will contain 0 (which is what NULL is) as a last value, and only as the last value, your solution would also work.

However, if 0 is a valid value in the array, then you will stop as soon as you encounter it.

Answer (score 2):

`while (data[i]!=NULL)` - there is no guarantee that `data[size]` would be equal to `NULL` as you suggested it would be. Without specifying `size` of the array, the value of `data[size]` could in fact be anything.

Note that accessing an array out-of-bound results in undefined behaviour. You will just get whatever value left over in that particular memory location, which *can* be gibberish, and no guarantee of any specific value (including `NULL`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first version has one major advantage: *it actually works!*

There are two reasons why yours won't:

1. Your version loops until `NULL` is found. NULL is either a pointer to 0 (which will not work), or 0. So what if there are zeroes in the array? You will get early termination.
2. Your version has not way of knowing when to stop. What if `value` is not found in the array? You will go on and on and on until there just happens to be 0 in memory. Arrays are not terminated with 0, only character literals are.